# Android - call TextWatcher for highlighted text

Tags: android, android-edittext

So I'm new to Android development and I'm currently figuring out TextWatcher.

What I'm attempting to do is attach my TextWatcher listener to an EditText widget and after the user has put in some text, say "Hello" and he highlights "llo" and types in r, I display the change in a TextView widget. For the above example it will display "llo --> r".

Now from what I've read and tried, since the textchangelistener is called every time the user types in something, my code ended up crashing when I ran it on my phone.

Is there a way to call the listener only when the highlighted text is changed so as to avoid calling it every time I'm just typing something in the EditText widget? I hope my question makes sense, I've tried looking around before posting here but I couldn't find anything.

Not looking for code, just some pointers so I can figure out how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity what error did you get when your code crashed from the textwatcher? Did you read the stack trace from Logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use a OnEditorActionListener instead of a textwatcher which I didnt know existed until now. It gets called when there is a change to a textview, and since edit text is a textview than it will work perfectly.

[Heres some info on the listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html)

Btw welcome to the android platform, I think you'll find that it is a rich language and definitely worth learning. If you really want some pointers your main point of reference should be [this link](http://d.android.com) which has many guidelines and pointers in the develop tab. Good luck

Comment: thanks! appreciate it. will look in to it when i get up tomorrow. lol i didn't read the stack trace in logcat, i figured it was happening because i didn't set up my textwatcher properly, assuming it got called for every input.